# Setting up a server with git

Tags: git, github, version-control, remote-server

I'm an intermediate git user, and I'm trying to set something like this up:

My friend and I have a repository on github, and he has git credentials, and I have my own git credentials, but we also have a remote server which we would like to pull changes onto.

Is there a specific way we set this up?  Or do I just make another normal git account for the server?

Also, we have a develop and a master branch, I would like to have two separate directories which default to either of these branches.

Essentially, either of us should be able to log in, navigate to dev or master, and do "git pull" without having to log into **our** git account, and have it naturally understand that it has to pull from dev if we're in the dev folder, or master if we are in the master folder.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Setting up a dedicated Git server that's nothing *but* a hosting site (a la GitHub or GitLab) is *hard*. GitLab, if you choose to use it, apparently comes with all the tools needed, but it's still going to be nontrivial. If you just want to have some server instance access some existing GitHub repository, that's relatively easy: create a machine key (aka "deployment key") and give that to the machine that does the deployment. Note that `git pull` means *run git fetch, then run a second Git command to use the fetched commits*, so ...

Comment: ... if you have two working trees (with a shared repository, or with separate repositories), and they have branches `master` and `dev` checked out respectively, and you set the default second command of `git merge` and the upstreams are set the usual way, a simple log-in-as-deployment-user, cd-and-run-git-pull will work fine.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys

Comment: @JohnHanley and Torek, thanks for the suggestions and pointing me to the right documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle deployment like this.  The first is to have each of you have your own SSH key which is registered with GitHub and log into the server, forwarding your agent (with `ssh -A` or an appropriate configuration option).  Then, when you log in, you can push or pull with your SSH key using an SSH remote.

The other alternative is to use a deploy key, which is better if you want to perform automated Git operations.  This is an SSH key that's specific to the repository and it's uploaded in the repository settings.  This allows that key to have either read-only or read-write access to just that repository, which you can then use in whatever way you like.